# can anyone please elaborate on cvWatershed() function

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation

cvWatershed() takes two arguments Iplimage *src_image and CvArr* markers.

Could anyone elaborate on the markers argument since I need to segment my image on the basis of my touch, so could the marker array be formed in realtime on the basis of my touch and then cvWatershed be called..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can form it realtime.

Taken directly from OpenCV documentation at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=watershed#watershed

> Before passing the image to the function, user has to outline roughly the desired regions in the image markers with positive ( > 0 ) indices... The markers will be “seeds” of the future image regions.

Comment: so basically the marker image would be a blank image with only certain pixel values as 1,2,..etc as per my selection??

Comment: @satyavrat afaik, yes indeed.